# Check average travel intervals for each station - pyhton

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame structure:

| id_trip | dtm_start_trip | dtm_end_trip | start_station | end_station |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-10-01 10:15:00 | 2018-10-01 10:17:00 | 100 | 200 |
| 2 | 2018-10-01 10:17:00 | 2018-10-01 10:18:00 | 200 | 100 |
| 3 | 2018-10-01 10:19:00 | 2018-10-01 10:34:00 | 100 | 300 |
| 4 | 2018-10-01 10:20:00 | 2018-10-01 10:22:00 | 300 | 100 |
| 5 | 2018-10-01 10:20:00 | 2018-10-01 10:29:00 | 400 | 400 |

And I would like to check, using python, how often a trip starts and ends in a given season. The idea was to do these average intervals per day, per hour and then in intervals of a few minutes.

What would be the best approach to doing this?

My desired output would be something to inform  eg: for station 100 on 2018-10-01, a travel starts, on average, every 4 minutes

Comment: do you want total usage per hour or minute etc? eg for the minute 10:20 to 10:21 there were 3 trips in progress?

Comment: @Riley Not exactly. What I need to know is. eg for station 100 on 2018-10-01, a travel starts, on average, every 4 minutes

Comment: ok, in that case create a column where you resample times to the intervals you're interested in then groupby station and time and perform a count. Eg if you resample on daily basis and find 200 trips for station 100 on 2018-10-01 then you have a trip every 24*60/200 = 7.2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you could group your DataFrame by different travels. Firstly, I would make a new column with a travel id, so travels starting and ending in the same stations can be grouped.
Then you can easily group those rows by travel id and get all the information you need.

Please note that your data sample does not include any "same travel". Also, consider providing a code sample for your data, it would be easier for us to work with and run tests.

Comment: thank you. But I think with this approach you suggest is not possible to have something like eg for station 100 on 2018-10-01, a travel starts, on average, every 4 minutes.

Comment: Ok, I might not have totaly understand what you wanted then. For this, you can make a DataFrame with only the travels starting from station `100`, then sort by start date and get the average time between two travels. Once again, I encourage you to provide us a sample of your data, with actual results it would be easier to answer your needs.

Answer (score 0):

First transform the date columns into Pandas DateTime

```
df.dtm_start_trip = pd.to_datetime(df.dtm_start_trip)

def deltas_mean(x):
    d = x-x.shift()
    return d.mean()


df.groupby('start_station').agg({'dtm_start_trip':deltas_mean})
```